# Add seed data to development database for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, seeding

I have a few tables that I would like to add about 10 rows of data to, in a manner that respects and illustrates their relationships.

- How can I add seed data (dummy data) to my applications' development database for testing?
  I'm hoping someone could point me to a rails friendly method for doing this.
- Is there an easy way to make the CRUD methods in each table perspective controllers?

Comment: I don't understand your second question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think i just found the answer to the second question. I believe that scaffolding can help me set up my CRUD controllers and my views?

Comment: Oh, yeah, a scaffold will create the CRUD functionality for you.  I would recommend it for learning, not when you are actually building applications.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what the `db/seeds.rb` file is for.

You can execute it with rake db:seed

The default contents of seeds.rb

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ :name => 'Chicago' }, { :name => 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(:name => 'Daley', :city => cities.first)
```

You can use ruby in this, so to insert 10 users:

```
1.upto(10) do |i|
   User.create(:name => "User #{i}")
end
```

Comment: so, i need to insert code into the seed.rb file then perform a rake? I was hoping for a more automated way to add dozens of rows of data

Comment: You can use loops as this is a ruby file.  You can also use the faker gem https://github.com/btelles/faker if you want to use real names, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, as this is **not** what the seeds file/task is for.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580031/rails-recommended-way-to-add-sample-data) for (IMO) a better answer.

Comment: Is the seed.db used only for production data and rake db:fixtures:load for development and testing??

Comment: @Taysky is correct. Seed is for genuine seed data that your app may have. For example,  a static list of planet names or roles. I would suggest creating a custom rake task under the db namespace. Use ActiveRecord to create many records via loops.