# The case of the disappearing ActiveRecord attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

Following the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24496452/102675 I wound up with the following:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Drop, create, migrate, seed and populate sample data'
  task seed_sample_data: [:drop, :create, :migrate, :seed, :populate_sample_data] do
    puts 'Sample Data Populated. Ready to go!'
  end

  desc 'Populate the database with sample data'
  task populate_sample_data: :environment do
    puts Inspector.column_names.include?('how_to_fix')
    # create my sample data
  end
end
```

As you would expect, I get `true` if I run `bundle exec rake db:populate_sample_data`

BUT if I run `bundle exec rake db:seed_sample_data` I get all the migration output and then `false`. In other words I can't see the `Inspector` attribute `how_to_fix` even though it definitely exists as proved by the other rake run. Where did my attribute go?

Comment: Basic question  - If you create an `Inspector` in the console, can you access `Inspector.first.how_to_fix`?

Comment: @fylooi yes I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a "caching" problem. Can you try the following?

```
task populate_sample_data: :environment do
  Inspector.reset_column_information
  # ...
end
```

*P.S. We used to have a similar problem working with different databases having the exact same schema (only except some columns here and there)*

Comment: I filed the issue in the wrong place. Refiled: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29448